# Non-Numeric Text Exception Handling HTML/Javascript/Netbeans

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I'm trying to make a currency converter for a netbeans project.
I have the basic outline of the application. I'm just stuck on the last details of the program. I have to handle an exception in case the user tries to enter a non-numeric text into the input amount.

Here are the specific instructions for this part of my assignment:

> Your application must handle the eventuality that the user could enter non-numeric text as the input amount.  If you attempt to parse such text into a number, your application will throw an unsightly exception.  You must handle this situation by catching such exceptions, not attempting any calculation and presenting the user with a fresh calculation screen that does not have any input or output amounts and where the currency codes are restored to their default values.

I'm really confused as how to go about this because I'm still not familiar with html or javascript. My professor also wants us to do use loops to populate the option tags on the fxCalc.jsp page here are his instructions for this part:

> You will break out of HTML with a scriplet and iterate through the currency codes contained in the String[] of codes discussed above.  You do this at the point in the HTML where you would populate the HTML option tags.  You can dynamically create the drop-down list box using a loop.  The loop variable (whatever you care to call it, but currency is as likely a candidate as anything else), can be used in a JSP expression which literally prints out the variable in the value attribute of the option tag.  You will mix HTML and scriptlets as shown in Chapter 5 of http://www.jsptut.com.  You will do so with a combination of loops and branching.  HTML code in your loop is repeated as if it was hard-coded multiple times.  You must also use if/else blocks to selectively print the HTML of your choice.  For example, imagine a user selects USD and GBP.  As your JSP scriptlet is iterating through the currency codes array to build the drop-down list box, you can condition the code to add the attribute selected to the option tag corresponding to the user-selected in and out currencies.  Doing this will allow the user-provided currencies (both “in” and “out” ) to be the selected ones.  This is shown in the screen shot below in which the user tries to find the conversion between 25 USD and GBP.  In addition, the input amount and calculated output amount are scriptlet-defined local variables that will appear as expressions in the value attribute of the “in” and “out” amount text boxes.

I would say I'm pretty much done with this project except for these two problems. So i'll provide the code I have so far. The project consists of: fxCalc.html, fxCalc.jsp, fxInit.jsp and FxDataModel.Java

**fxCalc.html**

```
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<style>

    h1{
        color: white;
        font-family: verdana;
        font-size: 200%;
        font-style: italic;
        text-align: center;
    }
    hr{
        color:white;

    }

    select{
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-right:10px;
    }
    input{

        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-right:10px;
    }
</style>


<body bgcolor = "blue">

    <h1>
        Money Banks F/X Calculator<br>
    </h1>
    <hr>
    <div align="center">
    <form name="fxCalc" action="fxCalc.jsp" method="POST">

    <select name="Currency1">
        <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
        <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
        <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
        <option value="USD">USD</option>
    </select>
     <input name="input" type="text"/>

    <select name="Currency2">
        <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
        <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
        <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
        <option value="USD">USD</option>
    </select>


        <input name="output" type="text" disabled="disabled"/>

        <br>



        <input name="submitbutton" type="submit" value="Convert" name="Convert"/>
        <input name="resetbutton" type="reset" value="Reset"/> 



   <form/> 
   <div/>
</body>
```

**fxCalc.jsp**

```
        <%@include file="fxInit.jsp"%>
<%      

        String Curr1 = request.getParameter("Currency1");
        String Curr2 = request.getParameter("Currency2");
        String inString = request.getParameter("input");
        String outString = request.getParameter("output");
        Double formInput;            
        Double Conversion;
        String[] currencies = fxDataModel.getFxCurrencies();
        try {
          formInput = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("input"));            
          Conversion = fxDataModel.getFxRate(Curr1,Curr2)*formInput;
         } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {

             formInput = Double.parseDouble("");
             Conversion = Double.parseDouble("");


         }




%>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>F/X Calculator</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <style>

        h1{
            color: white;
            font-family: verdana;
            font-size: 200%;
            font-style: italic;
            text-align: center;
        }
        hr{
            color:white;

        }

        select{
            margin-top: 30px;
            margin-right:10px;
        }
        input{

            margin-top: 30px;
            margin-right:10px;
        }
    </style>


    <body bgcolor = "blue">

        <h1>
            Money Banks F/X Calculator<br>
        </h1>
        <hr>
        <div align="center">
        <form name ="fxCalc" action="fxCalc.jsp" method="POST">


        <select name="Currency1">
            <% for (String currency : currencies) { %>
              <option value="<%=currency%>" <%=currency.equals(Curr1)?"selected":""%>><%=currency%></option>
            <%}%>
        </select>


            <input name="input" type="text" value = <%=formInput%> />

        <select name="Currency2">
            <% for (String currency : currencies) { %>
              <option value="<%=currency%>" <%=currency.equals(Curr2)?"selected":""%>><%=currency%></option>
            <%}%>
        </select>


            <input name="output" type="text" disabled="disabled" value = <%=Conversion%>>

            <br>


            <input name="submitbutton" type="submit" value="Convert" name="Convert"/>
            <input name="resetbutton" type="reset" value="Reset"/>  




       <form/> 
       <div/>
    </body>
</html>




**fxInit.jsp**

    <%@ page import="data.FxDataModel"%>

    <%!

    private FxDataModel fxDataModel;

            public void jspInit(){
            fxDataModel = new FxDataModel();

            }
    %>
```

**FxDataModel**

```
public class FxDataModel {

    //create array for currency codes
   private static final String[] codes = {"CAD", "EUR", "GBP", "USD"};

   //create second array for conversion     
   private static final double[][] rates = 
     { {1.0, 0.624514066, 0.588714763, 0.810307 },
       {1.601244959, 1.0, 0.942676548, 1.2975},
       {1.698615463, 1.060809248, 1.0, 1.3764},
       {1.234100162, 0.772200772, 0.726532984, 1.0} };

   public String[] getFxCurrencies(){
       return codes;
   }

   public double getFxRate(final String inNumber, final String outNumber){

       int Currency1;
       int Currency2;
       double rate;

        for(Currency1 = 0; Currency1 <getFxCurrencies().length; Currency1++){ //loops through currencies array to match currency1 to inNumber
            String inCurrency = codes[Currency1];
            if(inNumber.equals(inCurrency)){
                break;
            }
        }

         for(Currency2 = 0; Currency2 <getFxCurrencies().length; Currency2++){ //loops through currencies array to match currency2 to outNumber
            String outCurrency = codes[Currency2];
            if(outNumber.equals(outCurrency)){
                break;
            }
        }

         //uses the values found in the loop to calculate a rate of conversion in the 2d array   
         rate = rates[Currency1][Currency2];
         return rate;

        }


   }
```

I know this was a long post, but I figured its better than being ambiguous. Anyway if someone could help me figure out how to do the exception handling and the option tag loops in a scriptlet. I would really really appreciate it. I've spent several hours looking online and through this website and I still need help. Thank you!

Comment: Without going through the complete code: The first part is simply checking whether the user has entered a number or not. If you don't check an error will come and the rest of the script will stop, if you check first to be sure it is a number you can warn the user that it should be a number.

Comment: The second part, instead of the html code <select><option></option><option></option></select>. You only have <select id=currency1></select> and fill it dynamically with javascript.

Comment: Well the thing is I don't know how to check. The user enters a string initially and then it is converted to a double using the Double.ParseDouble() method. I was hoping for more specific answers because I wasn't able to find any through research. My lack of javascript knowledge also restricts me in filling the option tags dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

To validate the input, you can use [`NumberFormatException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) which is thrown by the [`parseDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)) method using a `try-catch` block. So for example, in the **fxCalc.jsp** you can do as follows:

```
<%      

        String Curr1 = request.getParameter("Currency1");
        String Curr2 = request.getParameter("Currency2");
        String emptyValue = null;
        Double formInput = null;
        Double Conversion = null;

        try {
          formInput = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("input"));            
          Conversion = fxDataModel.getFxRate(Curr1,Curr2)*formInput;
         } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
           emptyValue = "";
         }



        String[] currencies = fxDataModel.getFxCurrencies(); 

%>
```

After this, in your html code, you can check for `errorMessage`, and if it is not `null` it means the input was not a number, otherwise, the conversion can be done.

P.S. About populating the currencies dinamically in a loop, and reset the form in case of incorrect input:

```
<select name="Currency1">
<% for (String currency : currencies) { %>
  <option value="<%=currency%>" <%=currency.equals(Curr1)&&emptyValue==null?"selected":""%>><%=currency%></option>
<%}%>
</select>
<input name="input" type="text" value = <%=emptyValue==null?formInput:emptyValue%> />
//
<input name="output" type="text" disabled="disabled" value = <%=emptyValue==null?Conversion:emptyValue%>>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, one question about the loop. How would you implement the select attribute to the loop so that it remembers the selection of the currency from the first html page.

Comment: @DeathWish check the EDIT.

Comment: When I make it check for error message, what would be the best way to just refresh the page so that the form is reset back to the first html page instead of saying "Please insert a valid number!"

Comment: Also I found that when I try to use the try-catch block in the scriptlet, "formInput" and "Conversion" are underlined when I try to initialize the input text boxes. '<input name="input" type="text" value = <%=formInput%> />' Would declaring the variables outside the try-catch block and then just calling them inside of it fix this problem?

Comment: @DeathWish yes, declare them outside the try-catch block and initialize them inside.

Comment: Is there a way I could reset the form using the catch statement. My professor said to do this: 

- set two string variables that you use for the value attributes of the textboxes to empty strings ("")

- set Curr1 and Curr2 to the zeroth entry of the currencies array which will have to be moved before the try block so you have access to the value.

With these 4 variables in place, you should be able to reset the form in the event that the user enters invalid input.  That's all you need.

I keep getting a format error though whenever I enter a letter. Check the edit for the updated code.

Comment: @DeathWish Check the edit, i think this is what you wants. However, for the future, try to resolve the rest of things by yourself, otherwise you will learn nothing.